# Keep all Python scripts in one folder?

Tags: python, directory, organization

I'm working with some Python scripts that operate on files (compress them, calculate sizes, etc.) and create some other files (distance matrix, file sizes list, etc.). I have different groups of files that I need to keep separate (in one folder I have txt files, in another I have some midis...). Now I have a copy of the scripts in every folder (the txt folder, the midis folder...) but it's a mess, because I forget which one is the most recent.

My question is: is there a way to keep the scripts in just one folder (for example ./stuff/scripts) so that I can run them from the different filetype folders (./stuff/midi, ./stuff/txt) without having copies in each directory?

I'm new to Python and a newbie programmer, is this just a wrong approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many ways to do this properly, but the easiest way for a beginner is to put them all in one folder, e.g. `src` and put that next to the `midi` and `txt` folder. that way you can run them using relative paths like this:

```
python ../src/script1.py
```

the `..` moves you up (from e.g. `midi` to `stuff`) and from there you navigate to the proper path.

later you can learn about setting your `$PATH`, modules and much more...